# Add URL to aggregated variable SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, url, aggregate

I join two SQL tables (applications, areas_application1) and group they by area. 
In the first table I have columns url_title and url_link. I want to display for eah area a list of url_title 's and add href link to each title. I tried to aggregate url_title by space, but I don't know how to aggregate url_link for each url_title. 
This version does not work.

```
SELECT app.area, ar.cartodb_id, count(app.area),
array_to_string(array_agg(app.url_title), 
'<a href="app.url"</a><br />'), ar.the_geom_webmercator 
FROM applications as app 
JOIN areas_application1 as ar 
ON ar.name = app.area 
GROUP BY app.area, ar.the_geom_webmercator, ar.cartodb_id
```

Comment: what version of sql are you using? mysql, oracle? also it might help to put an expected result with your question so we know what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: It is CartoDB’s SQL API . The database behind CartoDB is PostgreSQL .

Comment: ok, I added the tag, what exactly is it that you want to do here? you want to return an <a> tag with a href but the string on the tag should be your app_url_title?

Comment: I want to return url_title split by comma or space and each title with hiperlink from url_link columns to go to that url page easy.

Comment: to concatenate values in posgresql you just need the || operator so just do: app.url_title || ' ' || '<a href="app.url"</a><br />"

Comment: How can I join this command with my array_agg function in my code?

Comment: you don't have to, the || operator concatenates your values to become 1 long string or am I misunderstanding what you are expecting as output? can you give me an example of your wanted output?

Comment: when I have just typed  app.url_title || ' ' || '<a href="app.url"</a><br />" I have an error "column "app.url_title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". But I don't want to group by title.

Comment: I want to display:     area: NN, url_title:  [Shop](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), [House](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), [Lake](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), [See](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Ah right my bad, I think you need to do : array_to_string(array_agg(app.url_title, '<a href="app.url"</a><br />'))

Comment: ok. it is right for query:  array_to_string(array_agg(app.url_title), '<a href="app.url"</a><br />') or string_agg(app.url_title, '<a href="app.url"</a><br />') but insted of right hiperlink I have got "https://tanpaska.cartodb.com/viz/7eb89174-dcf0-11e4-9db5-0e018d66dc29/app.url" if I drop "" I have got https://tanpaska.cartodb.com/viz/7eb89174-dcf0-11e4-9db5-0e018d66dc29/app.url%3C/a

Comment: the biggest problem here is that I don't have your data so if you could just give me 1 record from your table and the exact result you want it would be a lot easier to help you out

Comment: Here is my table https://tanpaska.cartodb.com/tables/applications/public but it don't show my url_tilte and urk_link. I want to group by area and return 1  area: NN, url_title: [Shop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183411/add-url-to-aggregated-variable-sql?noredirect=1#comment48472579_30183411), [House](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183411/add-url-to-aggregated-variable-sql?noredirect=1#comment48472579_30183411), [Lake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183411/add-url-to-aggregated-variable-sql?noredirect=1#comment48472579_30183411), 2 area: BB, title: Lake, See

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query should help:

```
SELECT 
  app.area,
  ar.cartodb_id,
  count(app.area),
  array_to_string(array_agg('<a href="'||app.url_link||'">'||app.url_title||'</a>'), 
' '),
  ar.the_geom_webmercator 
FROM applications as app 
JOIN areas_application1 as ar ON ar.name = app.area 
GROUP BY app.area, ar.the_geom_webmercator, ar.cartodb_id;
```